# Free UML drawing library for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I'm looking for a free .NET (C#) library which i can use in my program and simply draw UML diagrams (especially class diagram). I tried to used Netron Diagramming Library but it is kind of tricky.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [EasyDiagram](http://www.easydiagram.net/)?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your requirements you may be able to use the http://yuml.me/ REST api.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/numl/

From the home page:

> Library for manipulating UML 2.0 and MOF 2.0 models, for .NET, Mono,
>   and DotGNU. Provides serialization to/from XMI 2.1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need a library which allows me to present (display) uml diagrams graphically