# Generating XMI or graphic UML diagrams (not code documentation) in C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, uml, xmi

Is there any solution available for generating UML diagrams (or at least XMI files) in C#.NET?

Bear in mind that I don't want to reverse engineer my code but automate UML diagrams generation (different kind of them, mostly component diagrams).

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716119/free-uml-drawing-library-for-net nUML might work for you.

Comment: Thanks but in the end I used Enterprise Architect automation interface and it works pretty good.

Comment: Not sure if you can get the relevant documentation to use it